# Basis For Non-Compact Functions

Tags: functions, fourier-analysis

I am not a mathematician, so excuse me for my incorrect use of terminology.

What I would like to ask is if there are basis functions for non compact functions? For example Fourier expansion uses sine and cosine as basis. But this works only if the function doesn't go to infinity. Is there a more general basis, at least for some real valued functions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't believe there is a basis for $C(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$, the set of functions $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ in general. However, it is possible to construct a basis for $C_0(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$, the functions that go to $0$ as $x \to \pm \infty$.

Comment: You mean we don't know about it, or it is proven that there doesn't exist one?

Comment: It can be proven that there doesn't exist one for $C(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$ (the set of *continuous* real valued functions). I think so anyway.  I'll have to think about that...

Answer (score 2):

Hermite polynomials are an orthogonal basis on $(-\infty,\infty)$ with respect to the weight $w(x)=e^{-x^2}$, i.e. on the Hilbert space
$$
L^2(w)=\{\,f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}\text{ or }\mathbb{C}:\int_{-\infty}^\infty|f(x)|^2w(x)\,dx<\infty\}.
$$
Laguerre polynomials are an orthogonal basis on $(0,\infty)$ with respect to the weight $e^{-x}$.